# Data from textboxes not being saved in SQL database

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I am not sure if it's me or there's something wrong with my code. Whenever I try to add a new account, it is being "saved" and shown in my datagridview, however, when I check under the data set or the table data, it's not being saved (or updated). I am using Visual Studio 2013 and I just checked my Microsoft SQL version - 2012. I did what I found here and in other sites, like uncheck the "Prevent saving changes that require table re-creation"; and I also changed the "Copy to output directory to Copy if newer", oh, and I also changed the |DataDirectory| to the path of the 2 mdf files.

Sorry if I'm asking a question that was asked before. And... here's my code (this one is for change password form):

```
    If txtNewPass.Text = txtRetyped.Text Then
            Dim strSql As String

            Try
                Dim objAdap As SqlDataAdapter
                Dim objDt As New DataTable

                strConn = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\FHGES.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
                objConn = New SqlConnection(strConn)

                Dim s As String = "SELECT * FROM tblAccounts WHERE UName COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS='" & frmLogin.txtUname.Text & "'AND PWord COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS='" & frmLogin.txtPassword.Text & "';"
                objComm = New SqlCommand(s, objConn)
                objAdap = New SqlDataAdapter(objComm)
                objAdap.Fill(objDt)

                lblUName.Text = objDt.Rows(0)(4).ToString

                strSql = "UPDATE tblAccounts SET PWord='" & txtRetyped.Text & "' WHERE UName='" & lblUName.Text & "'"

                objComm = New SqlCommand(strSql, objConn)
                objConn.Open()
                objComm.ExecuteNonQuery()
                objConn.Close()

                MessageBox.Show("Saved new password, please re-login", "FHGES", MessageBoxButtons.OK)

                frmLogin.Show()
                frmLogin.txtPassword.Clear()
                frmLogin.txtPassword.Focus()
                Me.Hide()

            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.Message)
            Finally
                If objConn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
                    objConn.Close()
                End If
            End Try

        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Password don't match!", "FHGES", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
            txtNewPass.Clear()
            txtRetyped.Clear()
            txtNewPass.Focus()
        End If
```

Comment: Is this Visual Basic? The programming language.

Comment: You need to research sql injection. Your code is a textbook example of this vulnerability. You also should not be storing passwords as plaint text. They should be hashed and salted.

Comment: Have you tried running these update queries in SQL server itself?

Comment: @Maximus2012 yes it is.

Comment: @SeanLange I guess security isn't an issue atm. :) but thanks!

Comment: @alybaba726 nope. I'll try and see. :)

Comment: Here is the issue for the password thing. Most people have only a few passwords for most of their accounts. If your data is compromised you put those people's other accounts at risk. Sure it is probably their fault for not using a different password for every single account but people just don't do it very often. It is really simple to hash and salt passwords and is the responsible way to manage passwords.

Comment: You didn't mention sql injection. This isn't really an optional thing. If you don't protect your system from sql injection then literally anything can happen to your database. It doesn't take any longer to parameterize queries once you know how than to just write your basic query.